# When the user opens the app, is it possible to tell what their language is?

Tags: android, localization

I have a part of the app which is interactive and can only be used by English speakers. Is there a way to detect the user's language setting as they land on a page, so that I can dynamically hide some features which I only want to show to English speakers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check a device language using following code:

java.util.Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Locale.getDefault()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault%28%29)to get their current preferred locale.  From there, you can use [`getLanguage`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getLanguage%28%29) to look for the `en` language code, and `getVariant` if you are interesting in only US or other variants.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider localising your resources, instead of doing everything programmatically.